# Git commands failing with: `error: unable to start editor ''`

Tags: git, zsh

Yesterday I could run git command which might open an editor (like `git commit --amend`) just fine, but starting today it's failing with the following error:

```
error: unable to start editor ''
Please supply the message using either -m or -F option.
```

It's odd because this seemed to come out of nowhere.

I'm on macOS with `zsh` as my shell. I've specified a custom editor in `~/.gitconfig` (and nowhere else):

```
> git config editor.config
emacs
```

Emacs itself definitely works. I can also remove that section entirely or replace it with something else (like `vim`) and it gives the same error.

What gives?

Answer (score 0):

The crucial clue is that the editor name is `''` -- this is distinct from git complaining that it can't find Emacs. This can happen if `$GIT_EDITOR`, `$EDITOR`, or `$VISUAL` is set but empty. However note that `$GIT_EDITOR` will override any settings in your git configs, while the other two will not. Confirm this by running:

```bash
[[ -v GIT_EDITOR ]] && echo "GIT_EDITOR is set"
[[ -v EDITOR ]] && "echo EDITOR is set"
[[ -v VISUAL ]] && "echo VISUAL is set"
```

Unset whichever one is present:

```bash
unset GIT_EDITOR # or EDITOR or VISUAL
```

Note that `$GIT_EDITOR` takes precedence over any settings in your git configs, while `$EDITOR` and `$VISUAL` do not (so the latter cannot be the culprit if you configured git's `core.editor`).

Perhaps the git CLI should have better error messaging around this particular scenario.

Comment: If I understand the git man-page for _commit_ correctly, it not only honours `GIT_EDITOR`, but also `EDITOR` and `VISUAL`, so these could also be the culprit.

Comment: Good point; I've added this to the answer